# Битрикс, каталог и 404

Tags: битрикс, http-status-code-404

Подскажите как можно реализовать, и можно ли вообще такое сделать.
Есть каталог и ссылки типа example.com/catalog/section/subsection/item/
Сейчас если удалить этот товар, то по этой ссылке получаем заголовок 404 (что замечательно) и отрисовывает главную страницу каталога.
Возможно ли сделать так, что бы он отрисовывал не главную каталога, а раздел в котором был этот товар.

Например
*example.com/catalog/section/subsection/
для
example.com/catalog/section/subsection/item/*

и 
*example.com/catalog/section/
для
example.com/catalog/section/item/*

Comment: в настройках компонента проставьте настройки для 404 страницы. если нужно, то доработайте формирование ссылок перед выводом компонента и в нужные параметры компонента подставляйте свои данные.

Comment: Вот полная настройка 404 страницы, специально написали эту статью, чтобы раз и навсегда закрыть эту тему, так как это одна из самых распространенных ошибок: [1С-Битрикс - правильная настройка страницы 404](https://onlinebd.ru/blog/1s-bitriks-pravilnaya-nastroika-stranicy-404)

Comment: все зависит от того на сколько вы умеете программировать, сделать можно, формирование урл и 404 происходит на уровне компонента, там он "угадывает" урл. Если в кратце, то компонент комплексный он подключает шаблоны секций и элемента и поиска и фильтра.... Так вот, если создать в своем пространстве имен компонент и наследоваться от стандартного (желательно чтобы бытрикс был новый и это был класс) то логику 404 можно легко превретить во все что угодно